# When is it relevant to replace a table column by another table in a database structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I begin in databases and I wonder when it becomes relevant to transform a table field into a table in our structure. For instance :

```
+--------------+
|Cloth         |
+--------------+
|id            |
|name          |
|composition   |
|...           |
+--------------+
```

When does it become interesting to make a table Composition with one column name (with few repetitive values like Cotton, cotton bio....)

In advance thanks!

Comment: 'When does it become interesting to make a table Composition' - right up front..that way you can avoid misspellings, enforce referential integrity add compositions when desired etc,etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about when you want to make a reference table for the values in `Composition`.  Here are common situations when you would want a reference table:

- The same values are used across multiple tables and you want consistency.
- You have a set of value that you want to check for.  It takes additional effort to add the values into the reference table, and you don't want to do so for a field that allows arbitrary strings.
- You have additional information about each value, such as short names, codes, date of insertion, translation into other values and so on.

If you do use a reference table, I would suggest using an *integer* primary key for the table.  You should also properly declare foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If "composition" is not an attribute or a preparty, but an independent entity (or it takes a form of an entity in your application) then it is recommended to create a table for it.